# What is the topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ associated to each filter on $X$ called?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, filters

I think the following works: let $X$ denote a set equipped with a filter $\Phi$. Then its powerset $Y = \mathcal{P}(X)$ becomes a topological space as follows: for each $y \in Y$ and each $N \subseteq Y$, we assert that $N$ is a neighbourhood of $y$ iff there exists $\varphi \in \Phi$ such that for all $y' \in Y$, if $y \setminus \varphi = y' \setminus \varphi$, then $y' \in N$.

> **Question.** What is this topology called?

For example, in the case where $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $\Phi$ consists of all non-empty uppersets, we obtain a topological space $Y$ that looks a bit like the unit interval $[0,1],$ though it's not dense. We can obtain the unit interval as a quotient of $Y$.

Comment: *Remark.* It seems possible that this puts a uniform structure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, too. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: I don't know a name for this, but let me remark that there is a natural generalization to a topology on an arbitrary product of spaces indexed by $F$ (with your example being the case that all the spaces are 2-point discrete spaces).  When $F$ is the cofinite filter, this is the usual product topology, and when $F$ is the improper filter, this is the box topology.